# Buffer.toString in NodeJs omits decimals on whole number but not on float?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, tostring

So I'm trying to write a google cloud functions that runs everyday. It needs to get a csv file from a sftp server and process data in the csv file.

I'm using the ssh2-sftp-client plugin to get the file from the sfpt server and get it back as a Buffer. The problem I'm running into is that the toString method on Buffer straigt up omits decimals on numbers ending on ,00
Example of some data in the csv file:
[image]
From looking through some logs I can see the 600,00 gets changed to 600 and and 93,87 to "93,87".
[image]
Can I stop this from happening? Since it's a csv file I'm splitting the string on , as a delimitir.

I've tried checking my row of data on length to see if the number has decimals or not but I don't think that's a real elegant solution.

This is my code:

```
exports = module.exports = functions
  .region('europe-west1')
  .runWith({ memory: '8GB', timeoutSeconds: 540 })
  .pubsub.schedule('every day 22:00')
  .timeZone('Europe/Amsterdam')
  .onRun(async (context: any) => {
    try {
      const sftp = new client();
      await sftp.connect({
        host: host,
        port: 22,
        username: username,
        localUsername: localUsername,
        privateKey: privateKey,
      });
      const workingDirectory = await sftp.cwd();
      logger.log('cwd', workingDirectory);
      const exportFileList = await sftp.list('/Export');
      logger.log('list:', exportFileList);
      if (exportFileList.length > 0) {
        const exportFile = exportFileList[0];
        const downloadedFile = await sftp.get(`/Export/${exportFile.name}`);
        const fileInString = downloadedFile.toString();
        const rowsInFile = fileInString.split('\n');
        logger.log('rows:', rowsInFile);
        await uploadFileToStorage(downloadedFile);
        await sftp.delete(`/Export/${exportFile.name}`);
      } else {
        logger.log('no files in export');
        return await sftp.end();
      }
      return await sftp.end();
    } catch (err) {
      logger.error(err);
      return;
    }
  });
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)